# Div and its contents within banner-wrapper, resize with window, and mobile

Tags: html, mobile, resize, wrapper

I am working from a wordpress template (please keep reading) and am trying to get my new callout div, and the text inside it to resize, *within* the header "banner-wrapper, along with the browser window (hopefully mobile friendly too). If you have time to help, I'll gladly share my unpublished link with you.

I have been utilizing this code:

```
.calloutb {
    position:;
    width: 248px;
    margin-left: 752px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    height:auto;
    border-top: 10px solid rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.04);
    border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(182, 182, 182, 0.04);
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.29);
    margin-top: -404px;
}
```

Ideally, the final product will resize beautifully in real-time with the browser window on a monitor or mobile device.